# SharePoint Server 2013 installation prerequisite error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, installation

I am trying to install SharePoint Server 2013, I am trying it using en_sharepoint_server_2013_with_sp1_x64_dvd_3823428.

I first mounted it and when I did run prerequisites.exe its saying installed but when I am trying to run SharePoint again its saying dot net framework 4.5 required to be installed.

When I  tried installing net framework 4.5 separately its saying it already exists in OS. But still I am not able  to install SharePoint Server 2013.

Can anyone please help me how can I solve the error.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue usually occurs in case you are trying to install The Sharepoint 2013 SP1 on a machine already has .Net framework 4.6, 4.6.1, or 4.6.2 installed.

**Unfortunately**, The SharePoint 2013  is not able to detect the most recent .NET Framework versions, so it reports this issue incorrectly.

**Solution**

- **First**, If you are trying to install the SharePoint from DVD drive, Take a copy from the SharePoint Media to a writable location.
- **Second**, Based on the product you are installing, download the corresponding compressed file.

  - [SharePoint Foundation 2013 with Service Pack 1 fix](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/6/2/362c4a9c-4afe-425e-825f-369d34d64f4e/wsssetup_15-0-4709-1000_x64.zip).
  - [SharePoint Server 2013 with Service Pack 1 fix](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/6/2/362c4a9c-4afe-425e-825f-369d34d64f4e/svrsetup_15-0-4709-1000_x64.zip)
  - [Project Server 2013 with Service Pack 1 fix](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/6/2/362c4a9c-4afe-425e-825f-369d34d64f4e/svrsetup_15-0-4709-1000_x64.zip)
- **Third**, Extract the .zip file > Copy the .dll file to the Root SharePoint Setup” folder or Updates folder.
- **Forth**, Try now to run the Sharepoint Setup file that should now proceed without any issue.

For more details check [Setup is unable to proceed due to the following error(s): This product requires Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/10/27/this-product-requires-microsoft-net-framework-4-5-sharepoint-2013-setup-failed/#more-21295)